# differential equation with delay

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose, I have an differential equation with a fixed $\tau$ delay $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x(t)+\alpha x(t-\tau))$. Here $\alpha$ is a small parameter. When $\alpha=0$ its a simple Self-oscillatory differential equation with the T-period limit cycle, like in a Van-Der-Pol equation. Next, I know from numerical calculations, that when $alpha$ is enough(but still small) the solution became "pseudo" periodical with period $\tau$ (i define parameter $\tau< T$). How should I find this "enough" $\alpha$? "Pseudo" means that solution is a sum of normal $\tau$-periodical part and small fast unperiodical oscillations. Thank you!

p.s. For real $x(t)$ is a vector, $\alpha$ is a matrix.

Comment: It is a problem commonly seen by engineers. What they do is brainless Taylor expansion.